# How can I find all cities within a 50km radius?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I see that in `3.0.0-M01` there was a support added for `point()` and `distance()` added however I see no example on how we can use in the cypher query.

Basically I have many cities and its lat/long on the node properties and I want to find all the cities in the 50 km radius. is there a way we can achieve that with Neo4j 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add some place:

```
MERGE (a:Place {title: 'NY', latitude: 40.71427, longitude:-74.00597})
MERGE (b:Place {title: 'JC', latitude: 40.72816, longitude:-74.07764})
MERGE (c:Place {title: 'NA', latitude: 40.73566, longitude:-74.17237})
MERGE (d:Place {title: 'JC', latitude: 39.95234, longitude:-75.16379})
```

2) Find cities in the 50km radius from NY:

```
MATCH (a:Place {title:'NY'})
    WITH a
MATCH (b:Place) WHERE id(b)<>id(a) 
    WITH a, b, distance( point(a), point(b) ) as dist 
        WHERE dist<=50000
RETURN 
    a.title, b.title, dist
ORDER BY dist DESC
```

Comment: @Kiran If you use other keys to the coordinates, it is necessary to give them a part of the map to constructor of the point: `point({ latitude: a.lat, longitude:a.lon })` instead `point(a)`